# How to limit the number of minted NFTs

Tags: nft

How to limit the number of minted NFTs? I'm using OpenZeppelin, and I see the totalSupply query function, but no way to actually limit the number of minted NFTs

Answer (score 0):

On your mint function you can check the totalSupply is less than the amount you want minted.

Eg.

```
uint256 public maxMint = 1000;
function mint(uint256 _amnt) public {
    ...
    require(totalSupply() + _amnt <= maxMint, "This many cannot be minted at this moment");
    ...
}
```